# Symfony 2.3 installing bundles

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I'm using the latest Symfony - 2.3

I'm trying to install SonataAdminBundles.. In tutorial is said - add this to deps file.

```
[SonataAdminBundle]
    git=http://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Sonata/AdminBundle

[SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle]
    git=http://github.com/sonata-project/SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Sonata/DoctrineORMAdminBundle

[SonatajQueryBundle]
    git=http://github.com/sonata-project/SonatajQueryBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Sonata/jQueryBundle

[KnpMenuBundle]
    git=https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Knp/Bundle/MenuBundle

[KnpMenu]
    git=https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenu.git
    target=/knp/menu
```

I read there is no deps file in this version, there is composer.json for now, but when i opened composer.json i saw there is another syntax.

How should i install this bundles via composer?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you should install dependencies with composer whenever possible. It's the recommended way.

The `2.3` version of symfony doesn't include the `bin/vendors` script anymore as composer provides a solid way to resolve your dependencies.

You only need to add the following to your project's `require` configuration in `composer.json` and run `composer update -o` afterwards to get the dependencies via composer:

```
"require": { 
    "...",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "2.2.7",
}
```

`sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle` has a dependency with `sonata-project/admin-bundle` which in turn has a dependency with `sonata-project/jquery-bundle` and `knplabs/knp-menu-bundle` ( which itself has the dependency with `knplabs/knp-menu`).

Composer will fetch all the needed dependencies automatically.

Comment: So i need to install only "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "2.2.7" - the other bundles will install automaticly?

Comment: I would be very thankful if you give me some of your contacts (Skype would be great) for further advises.

Comment: yes the other bundles will install automatically. You can find me as user `nifr` on the `#symfony` channel in the `freenode` IRC network.

Comment: Okay, i'm not so active on IRC, dont you have skype please?